# magento 1.9 SSL issue

Tags: ssl, magento1.9.2.4

my magento 1.9 www.hafeezpk.com is not show SSL pad lock how to fix this issue please tell complete solution because SSL certificate already install in my website you can check below of this screenshot attachments my hosting company reply message read below also.

Hello,

Thank you for contacting support!

I was able to resolve the issue with your website redirecting by renaming the Magento cache at var/cache to var/cache.old to allow the cache to be regenerated. However, forcing https beyond this would require the assistance of a Magento developer. You may want to also consider posting a question on a forum like https://magento.stackexchange.com for further assistance with this.

Please let us know if you have any further questions; we are more than happy to help.

Best Regards,
Lain V.

InMotion Hosting

if you need i am provide my admin and c-panel access detail but private.

[image: please check this link below]

[image: please check this both attachment]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoaVF.png)

Comment: ok skype me khirade.vijay

Answer (score 0):

Your site is not showing the pad lock over https because it's loading assets (ie. js files and images) over http.

You can try configure your site's Base URL.  This is in Magento admin backend System -> Configuration -> General | Web -> Unsecure and Secure Base URL. Use https:// for both, and not http://.

Comment: please check below i am try but still not show SSL pad lock please check screeen shot and answer please of this issue

Comment: @Moinuddin try right-click on your site and "View page source". And on the source page hit ctrl-f and search for "http://" (without the quotes) to identify what you need to update.  Looks like you are loading Google fonts and also some jpg and png image files over http.  Google font is probably in your layout xml file.  Jpg and png may be loaded in template files and/or CMS pages/blocks.

Comment: still not solve this issue i don`t understand how to update http:// don`t show CMS pages/block how to replace http to https from file manager >.htaccess / other way to solve this matter from panel / if you don`t mind give me you email address i am sending you c-panel and admin access details .

Comment: my site is still www.hafeezpk.com not show SSL pad lock i am trying but still not fix this issue proper i don`t understand how to fix this issue from c-panl / magento admin if any body send me screenshot / video then i will try to fix this otherwise please any body give me your email / skpye then i will send you my access details you can do please.


view-source:https://www.hafeezpk.com/

Comment: @Moinuddin you should hire a Magento dev to resolve the issue for you and not give out login credentials to a live site like this.

Comment: i am not hire developer because i am student please guide me i am again try today change some http to https from CMS page/blocks                               
  And Magento admin backend System -> Configuration -> General | Web -> Unsecure show http and Secure show https and now not change please check this link https://ibb.co/C17wr7p

Comment: User007: now show SSL pad lock successfully thanks for your help

Comment: @Moinuddin good to hear you got it working!

Comment: User007:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260294/navigation-timeout-exceeded-magento-1-9/260318#260318

Comment: @User007please answer me this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260751/magento-product-slider-missing

Comment: how you solve i am facing same