# Navigation Timeout Exceeded magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

my site www.hafeezpk.com is not open in https://gtmetrix.com/ please tell me how to fix this issue [image: not open my site in gtmetrix]

https://gtmetrix.com/?job_error=UlsCBd7H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An external js script on your website is taking too long time to load. You need to remove it from your website

https://www.beetailer.com/javascripts/beetailer.js (21.253 Sec)

Comment: Salam Shoaib Munir, Your this link beetailer.com/javascripts/beetailer.js not open tell me how to remove Js Script please tell me complete process. please some screen shots links in my admin panel settings   https://ibb.co/ZmmB4Ty
https://ibb.co/NsgrmFf

Comment: find the file name **beetailer.js** in your project, you will find the place where it is included, remove the code and your website will work. This JS is taking so much time in your project. If it is calling from a module then you need to disable that module

Comment: @Moinuddin did you resolve your issue?

Comment: this issue solve from my hosting company

Comment: please answer me this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260751/magento-product-slider-missing